# SSH tunneling and running commands inside Docker image

Tags: ubuntu, bash, docker, ssh-tunnel

I'm pretty new to Docker and have a docker image, I need to do following:

- perform SSH tunneling to three different addresses from inside the
  docker image that to the outside.
- Then, I need to run a bash script inside the docker image.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom docker image based on your base docker image that implements your requirements.

Here https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#define-a-container-with-dockerfile there is a starting point

In your Dockerfile you can use:

- FROM to identify your base docker image
- COPY to copy your bash script to the docker image
- CMD to run one ore more commands(two ssh tunnel and your bash script) in your docker image

Here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ there are details on execute multiple commands on a docker container